Vercel deployment issues even after putting vercel.json file
I deployed a pinterest clone app which I made using Express and instead of the app, this is what's appearing when I click on the link:
Screenshot
Just the bare code from my index.js on the screen. I even put the vercel.json file in the root directory.
The code of which is as follows:
{"version": 2,
"builds": [
    {
        "src": "index.js",
        "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
],
"routes": [
    {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "/index.js"
    }
]}

Is the code correct? And if yes, then what more do I do to correct this?

Hi, Please see another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78846668/why-my-vercel-deployment-retunrns-me-index-js-file-insted-of-responce of the same issue. if no response from here, please ask here as well - vercel.community
